# PHP - runkit redefine method

Tags: php, oop, runkit

all my websites share a common starter, that deals with urls, file locations, etc.. There are 3 cases that need to be handled - is directory, file exists and file does not exist. Each application has unique code for each case. I decided to tinker with runkit a bit and I am trying to unify the code. Each case will be handled by a function, that could be redefined via runkit.

Consider this code:

```
class start {
   function __construct() {
       $this->options = array();
   }

   public function process() {
       // some code here
       $this->file_not_exists();
   }

   public function file_not_exists() {
       $this->options['page'] = 222;
   }

   public function redefine($what, $code) {
       runkit_method_redefine(get_class($this), $what, '', $code, RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC);
   }
}

$start = new start();

$start->redefine('file_not_exists', '$this->options["page"] = 333;')

//  page is now 333
```

This part works as intended. But when I try to change the code so the redefined method calls user function it works. But, for the love of god, I cant figure out how to pass the **$this** to the function.

Redefine method looks like this:

```
public function redefine($what, $code) {
    runkit_method_redefine(get_class($this), $what, '', 'call_user_func('.$code.'(), '.$this.');', RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC)
}
```

This doesn't work, no matter what I try (call_user_func_array as well). I just cant figure it out. For the record:

```
public function redefine($what, $code) {
    my_user_function($this);
}
```

Does work.

Any help is appreciated.

Note that this is just an experiment and I would like to know how to do this :)

Edit:
I get:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class starter could not be converted to string in blablallala\rewrite_starter2.php on line 153
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This doesnt work"? Compile error? Or what? How do you find out the not working thing?

Comment: If you have something like this `runkit_method_redefine(get_class($this), $what, '', 'call_user_func('.$code.'(), '.$this.');', `, then you cannot use something like this, `$start->redefine('file_not_exists', '$this->options["page"] = 333;')
`   How are you calling redefine??

Comment: $start->redefine('file_not_exists', 'test'); test being the name of the function I want to call

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope you get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{... removed as not necessary ...}

==== EDIT =====

[For the new problem, what you need is this]

```
<?
class start {
   function __construct() {
       $this->options = array();
   }

   public function process() {
       // some code here
       $this->file_not_exists();
   }

   public function file_not_exists() {
       $this->options['page'] = 222;
   }

   public function redefine($what, $code) {
       runkit_method_redefine(get_class($this), 
       $what, 
       '', 
       'call_user_func(array($this,' .$code. '),$this);', 
       RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC);
   }

   public function my_func($someobj)
   {
        print_r($someobj);
   }
}


$start = new start();
$start->redefine('file_not_exists', 'my_func');

$start->process();

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was copy/paste error on my part, I have double quotes there :) The problem is in this line runkit_method_redefine(get_class($this), $what, '', 'call_user_func('.$code.'(), '.$this.');', RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) function says that the first argument is '[callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)'. So to call the class method dynamically, you should pass the `array($obj, 'func_name')`.